# Create Dictionary for delegates and events

Tags: c#, events, dictionary, delegates

I want to create a dictionary like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
public delegate void CreateClickEvent(string value);
public event CreateClickEvent OnCreateClick;
public delegate void CreateHoverEvent(string value);
public event CreateHoverEvent OnCreateHover;

private Dictionary<string,Delegate> _myDictionary = null;

public MyClass()
{
    _myDictionary = new Dictionary<string,Delegate>();
    _myDictionary.Add("Click", OnCreateClick);
    _myDictionary.Add("Hover", OnCreateHover);
}

public void Call(string name)
{
    Delegate action;
    if (_myDictionary.TryGetValue(name, out action))
    {
        if (action != null)
            action.DynamicInvoke( "something" );
        else
            Console.WriteLine("null");
    } 
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Couldn't find action");
}
}

public class Tester()
{
    public Tester()
    {
        MyClass MyClass = new MyClass();

    myClass.OnCreateClick += RaiseCreateClickEvent;
    myClass.OnCreateHover += RaiseCreateHoverEvent;
}

public void RaiseCreateClickEvent(string value)
{
    ///do it here
}

public void RaiseCreateHoverEvent(string value)
{
    ///do it here
}
}
```

but unfortunately, the method **RaiseCreateClickEvent** or **RaiseCreateHoverEvent** (class Tester) is not calling from **Call** method (class MyClass). And it's not giving any error and **action** variable is looking null and printing **null**.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have dictionary of delegates, but it keeps *values* of your events at the moment of creation of the dictionary. At that point both `OnCreateXXXX` are `null`.

As an option can use dictionary of `Action` and call event in each so action will use current value of the event, not the initial one:

```
  private Dictionary<string,Action<string>> _myDictionary = 
       new Dictionary<string,Action<string>>();
         _myDictionary.Add("Click", s => OnCreateClick(s));
         _myDictionary.Add("Hover", s => OnCreateHover(s));
```

And use:

```
  _myDictionary["Click"] ("sometext");
```

Note good reading on delegates (and especially how `+` / `+=` impacts value) is available  http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx